# react native Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_checkbox:generateDebugRFile'

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

hi everyone today I tried run the android
hello, today I got an error when I tried to run the android of the project I've been developing for 3 months.

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
```

Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_checkbox:generateDebugRFile'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-community_checkbox:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Failed to transform react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-symbol-with-package-name, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
> > Could not find react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.71.0-rc.0/react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

```
at makeError (/Users/arslantek/Desktop/TTDeneme23Ocak/TTMedMobil/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
at /Users/arslantek/Desktop/TTDeneme23Ocak/TTMedMobil/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/arslantek/Desktop/TTDeneme23Ocak/TTMedMobil/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (/Users/arslantek/Desktop/TTDeneme23Ocak/TTMedMobil/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:142:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.

how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

BTW I fixed this problem by doing that

Replace this in android/build.gradle file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        exclusiveContent {
           filter {
               includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
           }
           forRepository {
               maven {
                   url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
               }
           }
       }

       // ... your repository definitions

    }
}
```

I refered that link https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210